# How do you find all connected sublists in a list? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So let's say we have the list [2,2,3,4]

Then how would you find all possible sublists that don't have any gaps in it

The the outcome would be-

```
[]
[2]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[2,2]
[2,3]
[3,4]
[2,2,3]
[2,3,4]
[2,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Is the ordering of the outcome important? What have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: `[arr[i:j+1] for i in range(len(arr)) for j in range(i,len(arr))]`.

Comment: `[l[j: j+ i]  for i in range(len(l)) for j in range(0, len(l) - i+1)]`. If you want it in that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do.

```
a = [2,2,3,4]

print([])   # print just empty list
for i in range(len(a)):     # get the rest
    for j in range(i+1, len(a)+1):
        print(a[i:j])
```